# Bathroom smells bad after new toilet install

Tags: bathroom, toilet, smell

Recently we noticed a bad smell coming from our downstairs bathroom.  When we investigated it further it seem that there was some leakage from base of the toilet. So had a plumber come out, took out the toilet, and informed us that the wax ring had failed.  So he replaced new wax ring and reinstalled the toilet.  The smell never went away and it actually got very bad.  The smell gets especially bad when the temperature outside gets very hot.  The smell is like a sewer like smell and its very bad.  The whole bathroom smells bad and we can pinpoint it coming from base of toilet since we are unable to smell it from sink or bathtub.  This bathroom does not have a fan, just a HVAC vent and window. What could the issue be here? Is it some sort of blocked pipe? blocked vent?

Comment: Blocked vents and pipes can certainly cause sewer gas/odors for various reasons, but it would be unlikely to come from a toilet that flushes properly. Did the plumber mention anything about water damage, or water/sewage intrusion under the floor? Is this on the 1st floor of a house on a raised foundation, where you could take a look in the crawlspace for sewage ponding/pooling or residual... stuff... from a leak?

Comment: I just had to return a new toilet that was cracked - fortunately I looked into its nether regions before placing it in service, said some very bad words about lack of quality control at formerly reputable brands, and stuck it back in the box. Not shipping damage - clearly a manufacturing defect that was ignored and shipped.

Comment: It is on the 1st floor on concrete foundation. We brought in a few water restoration damage companies to check out the area (leak only affected a few ceramic tiles by the toilet..no drywall damage behind toilet) and they pretty much recommended there is not much to do since it is so small and localized and underneath is concrete.

Comment: If, (and that's a big if) the leak is actually fixed, mopping the area (to the point of "flooding under the toilet", since that is where the problem is, but you probably don't want to remove the toilet again - though that would be an approach to get more direct access to the problem area) with a strong disinfectant solution (choose **one**, don't get creative and mix things together and kill yourself) to seep down where the stink is and kill it might help.

Comment: It is a possibility the new wax ring wasn't installed properly. As simple of a job it is, it does happen.

Comment: So when the plumber that installed the new wax ring and toilet again did not caulk the base of the toilet all the way. He left a small region in the back of the base uncaulked.  After a few days the smell was present day and night as you walked passed the bathroom.  So the last few days we tested something and put tape over the small region that was left uncaulked to see if that would make a difference.  So right now it is 1pm here on west coast and no smell is present outside or inside the bathroom (and it is already at 100 degrees outside).

Comment: Yesterday there was no smell too, until late in the afternoon when it was present again.  One other thing that I can think about is so far today that toilet has not been used or flushed yet.  Yesterday there was no smell until the toilet was used and flushed. So I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Another thing that we experimented today was that all day today we did not use the downstairs toilet or sink. The weather got pretty hot too around 104 degrees and there was no bad odor up to 9pm when we got back home. The bathroom window as open as normal. Then around 1030pm we used the kitchen sink to wash dishes and used the garbage disposal. Then about 30 minutes after we were done I went to the bathroom to check and I could smell the bad odor again before even entering the bathroom. And when I opened the door sure enough the odor was back. So I don't know what is going on now.